Movie about infectious monster/parasite
I don't remember much about the film ( it was potentially early 2000s) aside from a specific scene where a man is infected with this huge monster/worm/slug that kills him on the toilet, either crawling out of him or into him.
Afterwards, someone finds him dead on the toilet and the monster attacks after the person opens the lid.
The movies was really creepy and was filmed in English 
